# How to display a non savable secure pdf file in android?

Tags: android

I am working on android applications. I gone through the link http://dhruvvaishnav.blogspot.in/2013/05/download-file-to-your-android-device.html and able to display the pdf file. But now my problem is with security. When I display the pdf file in my android application it is possible to save that file. But according to my requirement the pdf file should not be saved. It should be only readable and should not be savable. What is best solution for this? 
Please anybody help me with this issue. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: But its already downloaded to the cache of the device ?

Comment: ok so for my requirement will this example doent work?

Comment: Once it's on the phone, there is nothing you can do.  If you want it to be secure, don't put it on the phone!

Comment: ok what lines of code do i need to remove in that example in order to make the file not to save in sd card and it should only display